# Convert an array string into an array

Tags: php

How do I convert `'["1","2-1","3-1-1"]'` into `["1","2-1","3-1-1"]`?

So, a string into an array.

I've tried casting `'["1","2-1","3-1-1"]'` to an array, but that does not work.

Comment: Is a json_decode no option for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `json_decode`:

```
$arr = json_decode($str);

$str = '["1","2-1","3-1-1"]';
$arr = json_decode($str);

var_dump($arr);

array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "2-1"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "3-1-1"
}
```